# SVProgressHUD likely HUD in landscape or Horizontal mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mbprogresshud, svprogresshud

I'm writing a view in "landscape mode" implement by changing the view's transform. And I need a Hud 4 showing infos in this "landscape mode"(I've disable the landscape left and right mode). I've searched the API of SVProgressHUD and seem there's no API of changing it

Any Suggestion?

**PS: I'm not in landscape mode But trying implement a landscape likely HUD in the Portrait**

Comment: You can use https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Are wah Dhanesh, You are here :)

Comment: if u used the view transform ,viewcontroller does not rotate, the viewcontroller view only rotate , in here you can't get the landscape